# Scraping the AJAX websites with Scrapy

Tags: ajax, scrapy

I am searching the answer for my question since last two days but now i am frustrated. I found a lot of stuff about this but nothing helped me in achieving my goal. The purpose of this long paragraph was to aware you that please don't link the previous answers of stackoverflow for reference. Kindly provide me simple & neat solution/answer.
I want to scrape the players data from https://www.premierleague.com/players
but i face ajax while scrolling down the page.
My teammate asked me not to use selenium. He asked me to only use Scrapy for this purpose.
So kindly tell me in easy word if it is possible with Scrapy or not.? & if possible then how.
I will be thankful to you.

Answer (score 0):

Its easy

Open Inspect Element or Firebug

Switch to Network tab and then click on XHR

And then start scrolling down the page

You will see they are sending AJAX requests

Just check which URL they are sending requests to, and check what form-data is being sent along

```
headers = {
    'Referer': 'https://www.premierleague.com/players',
    'Origin': 'https://www.premierleague.com',
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/69.0.3497.100 Safari/537.36',
    'DNT': '1',
    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8',
}

params = {
    'pageSize': '30',
    'compSeasons': '210',
    'altIds': 'true',
    'page': '0',
    'type': 'player',
    'id': '-1',
    'compSeasonId': '210',
}

yield Request('https://footballapi.pulselive.com/football/players?%s' % (urllib.urlencode(params)), headers=headers)
```

Comment: To continue paging, you can loop through a `range()` setting the `'page'` param to a counter in the loop.